# What is the best way to design/process in Java 8 ordered calls on different methods

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8, method-reference

My question is regarding design

I'm trying to design order/sequential calls based on different methods.

Suppose my Class :

```
public class Foo {

    public Object method1(String a){
        // impl1..
    }


    public Object method2(List<Object> list){
        // impl2..
    }

    public Object method3(Map<String,String> map, Object otherStuff){
        // impl3..
    }

    // other different methods ....
}
```

I want to follow this concept 
http://qrman.github.io/posts/2017/02/09/pipeline-pattern-plumber-quest

But my difference is that I use the only 1 class with multiple methods, if i had different services I would create new class to each service with interface implementation as in the link , but my purpose is create list of order methods inside 1 class that will iterate and execute them...

I was thinking about some method reference based on java 8

like described here : https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx

```
basic idea ?

List<> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Foo::method1)
list.add(Foo::method2)
list.add(Foo::method3) ...

forEach ..list -> execute
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you want to call `method2BBB` with the output of `method1AAA` (and so on..)?

Comment: @user7 , edited my question , I need a way to process order method calls and execute them

Comment: Which parameters are given to methods `mehtod[1-3]` ? And what do you want to do with returned objects ?

Comment: @ Benoit  , nothing to do with return object , just run methods with ordered call. I put return type as Object case it legacy code that cannot be changed. The arguments are different from method to method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because formal and actual arguments vary from one method to the other, you cannot use method reference. **Lambdas** should do the job:

```
    List<Consumer<Foo>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add((foo) -> foo.method1("a"));
    list.add((foo) -> foo.method2(new ArrayList<>()));
    list.add((foo) -> foo.method3(new HashMap<>(), "Other stuff"));

    Foo foo = new Foo();
    list.forEach(fooConsumer -> fooConsumer.accept(foo));
```